# NetworkManager upgrade from 1.34 to 1.36 breaks WireGuard configuration "No VPN gateway address received"

Tags: linux, vpn, networkmanager, wireguard

This morning I have upgraded `networkmanager` and `libnm` from 1.34 to 1.36. Unfortunately my so far working WireGuard VPN configuration shows now:

```
Feb 25 12:11:50 methadon NetworkManager[642]: <warn>  [1645787510.4775] vpn[0x55f6b08389d0,caae3dcd-fbd7-48aa-ab98-67ca7def0782,"stargate-vpn",if:27,dev:2:(stargate-vpn)]: config: no VPN gateway address received
Feb 25 12:11:50 methadon NetworkManager[642]: <warn>  [1645787510.4775] vpn[0x55f6b08389d0,caae3dcd-fbd7-48aa-ab98-67ca7def0782,"stargate-vpn",if:27,dev:2:(stargate-vpn)]: did not receive valid IP config information
```

I've checked the VPN configuration with `nmcli c show stargate-vpn` and `ipv4.addresses` and `ipv4.gateway` is correctly set. Now I downgraded with `pacman -U file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/networkmanager-1.34.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/libnm-1.34.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst` and it works again.

What is the issue with NetworkManager 1.36? I tried to find some changelog or info about this, but I couldn't see any change to WireGuard. Where would you report this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your situation is the same as mine then you may still be using the `aur/networkmanager-wireguard-git` plugin.

NetworkManager has a builtin wireguard manager now so you will need to uninstall the AUR plugin and migrate your config to the builtin one. Your old config can be found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Comment: Thank you! As you said, I had to uninstall `networkmanager-wireguard-git` and create a new VPN connection via `nmcli`. Then I could connect to it with `nmcli c up new-wireguard-vpn`.